# Self-contained Hello World type example for NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, nhibernate

I've been fussing around with NHibernate tutorials for months (yeah...literaly) with no success. I wanted to just get a basic "hello world" level example down pat so I could work with it and massage it into a proper use case but I can never get past the deprecated code or missing library files.

I can only assume that it is me who is at fault because of NHibernate's popularity. Would someone pleeeeeeasee lead me to a self-contained example that I can just download and run? I would absolutely appreciate it.

Comment: http://sdesmedt.wordpress.com/2006/04/05/hello-world-with-nhibernate/

Comment: Unfortunately this article is from 2006 when NHibernate was on version 1. The link to download NHibernate 1 is broken and I cannot continue =/

Comment: Try this, its from a presentation I did late last year with NH3.2. http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/nhibernate-32-nxtgenug-presentation-at.html This blog post has a link to download code etc. And yes I am the blg owner :)

Comment: Try this: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2012/08/solving-nhibernate-thenfetchmany.html Or this: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/05/fluent-nhibernates-auto-mapping-impress.html Don't download NHibernate files manually, use Nuget instead, and use Fluent NHibernate (this will automatically download the dependent NHibernate components), so you don't have to do your mapping in XML

Comment: You can get the code here: https://github.com/MichaelBuen/Demo_NHibernate_ThenFetchMany_Problem_And_WorkAround

Comment: Remember the source code is more of a reference than anything with tutorials...

Comment: Googling "nhibernate example" yields more than enough resources.

Comment: Many thanks to Nate, Rippo, and Michael. I will give your suggestions a try and come back with any questions if I get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to everyone (with the exception of Diego) for their help. Special thanks to Michael Buen for his suggestion with using Fluent NHibernate.

There is a great example of NHibernate 3.0 in action here that I got to work: http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/02/20/Linq-to-NHibernate-Tutorial.aspx

Now all I need to do is learn exactly what's going on and mold it to my uses.

Comment: Link no longer exists